# How to use JWT from social auth to fetch the respective user of django.contrib.models.user

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt, single-page-application, django-authentication, django-socialauth

Maybe I am missing something fundamental about JWT theory and concept, but I tear my hair on my head trying to understand the following.

Right now I have a login and signup powered by [REST framework JWT Auth](https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/). The flow is like this:

1. I create a `django.contrib.auth.models.user` instance
2. Call REST framework JWT Auth endpoint to get a token based on username and psw

In my settings.py I have

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ), ...
}
```

Also, I have `MyModel` which has a foreign key referencing `User` which stores some user data (say, her shopping list). So I use the JWT token to fetch the user shopping list.

Now I need to add social auth feature for the users. Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595507/django-rest-framework-social-auth-with-jwt), I get the token from FB. But the problem is that I do not undestand how should I associate this token with a `django.contrib.auth.models.user` instance. More specifically,

1. How do I actually fill in the fields first_name, last_name, email etc... of the `User` instance? I undestand that this info should be somehow included in the payload part of the JWT?
2. When authenticating views to fetch user shopping list, how should I tell Django that the token I included in the header is actually originated from FB, rather than REST framework JWT Auth ?

UPDATE.

Do I understand correctly, that, for example, in case of FB, I should just send a request to FB to get the token along with email, name, and say, photo of the user, and in case of success, I should fall back to the procedure desribed in the beginning of the question (create my 'native' django.contrib.auth.user instance, obtain Django JWT token) and forget about FB token at all ? But that would mean that the `password` field in my User model should become nullable.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost correct .

Those are the steps to follow.

1. Pass the token to your django rest server and server will verify the token and return decoded token. Please see [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/debug_token) .
2. After successful validation, you should either create a user by ID (get from above link's response) or fetch user by ID. All required information will be in response of above link. You just need to map the keys to your django model columns.
3. During creation of user you should **set unusable password for that user instead of null.** Please see django user manager to [set unusable password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_unusable_password).
4. Now you get your desire user from your system. You can easily generate JWT token from your system for that user and respond back that own system generated token to your user.
5. Each next subsequent API call; your `rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication` will validate, fetch user and attach that user to `request`.

You can experiment with your jwt token [here](https://jwt.io/). That token can be decoded as json payload and you can access that json by key and value.